# Sliding tefillin into place

Tags: halacha, tefilin

If one accidentally tightens his tefillin onto the wrong part of his arm, can he fulfill the mitzva by then sliding the tefillin into the correct place?

Comment: Furthermore, if tefillin is attached so loosely so as to be slidable, is it even considered tightened?

Comment: I don't mean easily sliding the tefillin. More like pulling on the straps multiple times, in order to slowly move it into place. Maybe there is a difference. When you slide, the straps never stop touching your arm, but when you pull on the straps, it seems you stop fullfilling the mitzva for a second because the strap isn't completely in contact with the arm.

Answer (score 1):

The Halacha is that when one slipped slightly, you'll need to make a beracha ([Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayim 25:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.25.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> Someone who puts his tefillin on multiple times in one day has to make the berachot each time. **This includes replacing them if they slipped slightly**, (Note: If he only displaced one of them, he only has to make one blessing.) even if he moved them himself intending to replace them immediately

So, according to Orach Chayim 25:12, you can replace them **if they slipped slightly**.

Similary, regarding your question, the ["Ask the Rabbi"-section from Eretz Hemdah explains](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/qna.asp?lang=en&pageid=&cat=12#:%7E:text=It%20is%20noteworthy,is%20generally%20best.):

> It is noteworthy that many Acharonim do not follow the Shulchan Aruch’s (OC 25:12) ruling to make a beracha when returning tefillin that slipped out of place. The Shelah explains that, when making the original beracha, one’s intention is to have it extend until the end of tefilla regardless of such breaks. Although there is not unanimity on the matter, that seems to be the more accepted practice (Mishna Berura 25:42; Kaf Hachayim 25:77). Therefore, it is not necessary to determine if the tefillin slipped so much to break the fulfillment of the mitzva. This along with the answer to your question allows one to rectify the situation and continue tefilla without fanfare, which is generally best.

See also this explanation on [Halachipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Putting_On_and_Removing_Tefillin#:%7E:text=if%20possible.%5B86%5D-,If%20One%20Mistakenly%20Put%20on%20the%20Tefillin%20Shel%20Rosh%20First,yad%2C%20and%20then%20re%2Ddon%20the%20Tefillin%20shel%20rosh.%5B88%5D,-If%20One%20Only) which explains that if the Tefillin shel rosh is incorrectly placed, it should be taken off and replaced on the right place. Please note (thanks to N.T.) that this is the case only if the Tefillin shel yad is not placed yet.

> However, if one put the Tefillin shel rosh on incorrectly, one should take it off, put on the Tefillin shel yad, and then re-don the Tefillin shel rosh

Comment: The case in Halachipedia is only when the person did not put on the Tefilin shel Yad yet. If you did, just slide the shel Rosh into place.

Comment: @N.T. I need to check. May be an Ashkenaz-specific difference, because we make a second berakhah on Shel Rosh. May also be impacted by the Arukh haShulchan's chiddush that we Ashkenazim aren't making a birkhas hamitzvah on the shel rosh, but a birkhas shevach at being able to carry Hashem's "name" in this way. However, just back from vacation and have a lot of work to catch up on. So, may not get around to doing that check. Depends on whether I can remember days from now.

Comment: Go ahead and check, but I'm pretty confident you'll agree. The lomdus of the bracha should not matter.